# Is it correct to use "are you" instead of "if you're"?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, questions

As an example:

> This is a good read, are you interested in more related topics.

What are these type of sentences called? Does it follow the same grammar as:

> Should you require more information please do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: Is the first example intended to be a question, or should it say "if you are interested..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is a good read, are you
>   interested in more related topics.

This is what we would call a comma-splice or run-on sentence. It is two independent clauses connected by a comma. Normal practice in standard written English is to separate these into two separate sentences or else use a semicolon to divide them:

> This is a good read. Are you
>   interested in more related topics?

or

> This is a good read; are you
>   interested in more related topics?

The second sentence is an example of a conditional sentence, and *should* is used as a (perhaps more genteel) replacement for *if*.

I don't see that these two sentences represent a single type, however. What are the commonalities you are trying to identify?

Edit: I forgot the question in giving my answer. "Are you ...?" is a declarative sentence cast as an interrogatory. "You are interested ..." would be declarative; reversing the order of subject and copula ("Are you ...") and adding a question mark makes it interrogatory. "Should you require ..." is a conditional clause expressing an untested possibility, followed by a polite imperative. The form is *if X then do Y*. Use either when you are asking for more information, but use the conditional clause only when you are setting specific conditions for the clause that follows.

Examples of conditional clauses:

> If it rains tomorrow, the farmers will
>   be happy.
>
> If I get good marks in college, I may
>   get into graduate school.
>
> Here's a bowl of popcorn, should you
>   feel like a snack during the movie.
>
> If you are ever tempted to light a
>   match while filling your gas tank,
>   please notify me so I can stand far
>   away.

Comment: +1 for telling us to not play with fire. :)

Comment: So is this sentence gramatically correct? `This is a good read, are you interested in more related topics.` Does it have the same meaning as `This is a good read, if you are interested in more related topics.`

Comment: @Hamid: It doesn't have the same meaning. The first makes a direct inquiry in the second clause; the second sentence uses its second clause to qualify the first clause: it says, in effect, that the book is a good read *only* if the listener is interested in the topics.